# GridBagLayout ignoring weight distribution due to fixed-size JPanel

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

My UI is split into two panels, lets call them *NormalPanel* and *SpecialPanel*. *NormalPanel* is supposed to take up 25% of horizontal space and *SpecialPanel* the other 75%. To achieve this i have used

```
gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] { 1, 3 };
```

The Result :

[image: Correct Display]

The problem i am running into is due to the properties of the *specialPanel*. It is a JScrollPane containing a fixed-size Panel. This means that whenever the JFrame gets large enough to display the entire fixed-sized Panel it ignores the weight distribution and just displays displays the entire Panel.

The Problem :

[image: Wrong display]

**How can i stop this from happening ?**

The code i used to create the examples :

```
public MyWindow() {

    GridBagLayout gbLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    // This makes the first row take 100% of the space (We only have one row)
    gbLayout.rowWeights = new double[] { 1 };
    // This makes the second column take up 3 times as much space as the first
    gbLayout.columnWeights = new double[] { 1, 3 };

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = gbc.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;

    // Initialize the panels
    normalPanel = new JPanel();
    normalPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    specialPanel = new SpecialPanel();
    contentPanel = new JPanel(gbLayout);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    contentPanel.add(normalPanel, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    contentPanel.add(specialPanel, gbc);

    setContentPane(contentPanel);
    setSize(1280, 720);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyWindow window = new MyWindow();
}

/**
 * 
 * This panel has a ScrollPan which is displaying a fixed sized panel.
 *
 */
public class SpecialPanel extends JPanel {

    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JPanel scrollPaneView;
    private JPanel fixedSizePanel;

    public SpecialPanel() {
        fixedSizePanel = new JPanel();
        fixedSizePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,720));
        fixedSizePanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1280,720));
        fixedSizePanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1280,720));
        fixedSizePanel.setBackground(Color.blue);

        scrollPaneView = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        scrollPaneView.add(fixedSizePanel);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(scrollPaneView);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(scrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(scrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED); 

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        this.add(scrollPane);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GridBagLayout is... *counterintuitive* with the way it distributes space. It first "asks" the components what size they want to be and gives them that space, only after that is the remaining space distributed based on the weights.

To work around this extend the panels you are adding to the GridBagLayout and override their `getPrefferedSize()` method like this.

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension();
}
```

Now the panels will "tell" the layout that they don't want any space and the layout will therefore distribute all the space based on the weights.

Comment: Ah, i misunderstood you on the last question and didnt override getPrefferedSize on the Panel actually added to the gridBagLayout, but the panel inside of the scrollPane. I just tested the way you ment it and it works, thank you !